# How to track user clicked Done - YouTube API onStateChange iOS

Tags: ios, swift, youtube, youtube-api, cocoapods

I am using the CocoaPod library [Swift-YouTube-Player](https://github.com/gilesvangruisen/Swift-YouTube-Player). I noticed that the API get an onState of data = 2 for both when the user clicks the `Done` and the `|| (Pause)`. See below the webview delegate returns the onState from the API.

```
ytplayer://onStateChange?data=2
```

How do you differentiate from the Pause and the Done? As obviously they are not the same, and the Done I aim to use to dismiss the YTPlayerView?

Comment: Although not an answer to your question, I should note that the only way to play YouTube videos in an iOS application without breaking their Terms of Service is to use a webview or [YouTube's iOS Player Helper](https://github.com/youtube/youtube-ios-player-helper)

Comment: Yes, that is correct. I noted that I am using Swift-YouTube-Player library. The webview response for pause and done are the same.